# Call event outside from class without reference

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, events

I want to call a C# ContentDialog from another class like:

```
var myDialog = new MyDialog();
await myDialog .ShowAsync();
```

But I do not want to have a reference to this dialog in the class.
Later I want to access the dialog to change the state of a process bar.
My Ideas was to create an event inside of myDialog which is invoked by a method of the constructing class.
Is this possible or are there other possibilities to get this done?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: how do you expect to call some member in a class without having any kind of a reference to that class? What is your *actual* problem with having that reference?

Comment: you need at least a DLL/EXE, i.e. the binary form of the Assembly, and load it into your 'AppDomain'. You could then create the instance by Reflection/Activator and cast it to `Window` and invoke `ShowDialog`on it

Comment: *Later I want to access the dialog to change the state of a process bar* Well, then you do want a reference, don't you? Or what is your definition of a reference?

Comment: 1) Please edit question to make it clear. Show that code snippet inside some class declaration, and instead of "the class", say that class name, or MyDialog - whichever class you mean. 2) **show whatever code you can** related to your idea. At minimum, show declaration of MyDialog, *with that event* you talked about. Then its easier to clearly communicate how to set up that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont get away without any reference to your `myDialog` instance or a member of that instance (e.g. a reference to a method that handles an event). That is because there is no way to access something that you dont know anymore.

One solution could be as follows (which is probably what you had in mind already):

- Create a `MyDialog` instance `myDialog`.
- Save a reference to a `UpdateStatusBar()` method of your `myDialog` instace. This could be done by adding the method to an event in your calling class:

```
//event
public event Action NewStatusAvaliable;

//event handler assignment (without arguments)
NewStatusAvaliable += myDialog.UpdateStatusBar;
//or with arguments
NewStatusAvaliable += () => myDialog.UpdateStatusBar();
```

- Call `myDialog.ShowAsync();`